# Is Xcode required to install Qt Creator with Nokia Qt SDK on Mac?

Tags: xcode, qt, qt-creator

I want to start developing apps in Qt for Nokia Belle/Meego/BB10 Platforms.

I have downloaded the Nokia Qt SDK 1.2.1 (including Qt 4.7.4, Qt Mobility, Qt Quick and other components).

I'm trying to install Nokia Qt SDK on a Mac, but it asks for Xcode. I have Xcode, but don't want to install it because it occupies a lot of space. Do I need it if I have Qt Creator? What does it need it for???? I thought Qt Creator can compile things itself. Can I uninstall Xcode after I install the SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt Creator is just an IDE. It needs the entire C/C++ development environment. Xcode provides such an environment.

The Qt SDK 1.2.1 is *very old*. Unless you need it to support an old Nokia platform, you shouldn't be using it. Go to [qt-project.org](http://download.qt-project.org) and get yourself a recent version of Qt (5.1.1 at the moment). It comes with Qt Creator. You still need Xcode for the compilers for the **desktop** platforms.

The SDK should come with compilers and simulators for the target devices, but I don't know offhand if it will need some non-compiler tools from Xcode.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to start cleaning that old computer then...
Yes, I know that SDK is outdated, but it's required by Nokia because they put some specific components I'm going to need...
I guess I'll also need Qt5 for BB10 development...

Comment: The simplest solution to the "cleanup" is to get a bigger hard drive, do a binary copy of the old to the new (use a linux rescuecd boot disk), then boot on the new disk and enlarge the partition.

Comment: I think I'll backup the old user files and reinstall OS X, then I surely will have around 80 GB free (I have only 20 left now), but thank you for the suggestion. That should be enough space, I hope...

Comment: An OS X install disk with its Disk Utility can also be used to do a disk-to-disk transfer, with nicer tools. I'm just so used to using `dd` from [rescuecd](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) I keep forgetting the install disk :)